# Plotting Incorrect dimensions

Tags: r, plot

This might be an easy question to answer which has been frustrating me a lot recently. My ultimate goal is to overlay observational length data onto my length graph from the model. I have a model that functions by time - written as follows:

`times <-seq(1, nrow(Mussel_Water_Data),1)`

I could use `730` instead of `nrow(Mussel_Water_Data)` because that's how many observations I have in the data set to run the model (daily water temp, etc.). However, my length data has only `455` observations. Hence, the discrepancy.

I pulled my length data from the data set:
`Mussel_Daily_LengthAS=data.frame(Mussel_Daily_Length$AS_length)`

finished the model: 
`sol <- ode(state, times, Deb, param)`

And then I tried to plot it:
`plot(sol, which = "L", obs= Mussel_Daily_Length$AS_length)` and I get the following error message:
`Error in obs[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions`

My question is: how would I be able to plot the two even tho I have different numbers of observations?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite follow your question, but you can always add stuff after plotting e.g. by using `points` ([tutorial](http://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-add-points-to-a-plot-in-r/)). That is, `plot()` first and then add whatever using `points` or `lines`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please pop over to this post on how to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: What I would like to do is overlay the data and negate the fact that there is missing data. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.